# Accessing Form elements using ID

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

This came as a surprise to me but I have a simple form with 3 fields in it. The fields dont have a "name" attribute to it. They instead have an "id" attribute.

However. I can still do a

```
var f = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
alert(f.elementID);
```

to access the element. I thought to access form elements in that way, the "name" attribute is necessary.

I couldn't find any explanation somewhere for such a behavior. Any pointers ?

**EDIT:**

I think there is some confusion regarding my question.

my form fields dont have a "name" attribute. They have an "id". Still, I can do this :

```
myform.elementId
```

to access them.The question has nothing to do with getElementsByTagName.

Comment: Perhaps you'd get better explanation if you remove the `getElementsByTagName` function because people seem to think that's where your confusion lies. Just put in your example `myform.foo` or something and ask why `foo` works even when it's not a 'name'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns all elements of the given tag. (In your case, all `<form>` elements)

It doesn't return all element that have a `name` attribute, as you seem to be understanding it.

In your case, you could call `getElementById` to return the (single) element that has the given ID.

---

**EDIT**: I think I'm misunderstanding your question.

If you're asking why you can still write `myform.elementId`, that does use the element's ID.

Comment: @sLaks doesnt that work with the element name ? maybe it works both with myform.elementName and myform.elementId

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing getElementsByTagName with getElementsByName.  TagName is picking up <form> but Name is <form name='XYZ'>.

Comment: From my understanding, that's not his question. His question is why `form.foo` work when `foo` is an id, not name.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use

```
var f = document.getElementByID('some_id');
alert(f.value);
```

Comment: No, since it is Id not ID and form elements do not have a value property (unless they contain a form control that is named 'value').

Comment: The OP States: The fields dont have a "name" attribute to it. They instead have an "id" attribute. --- This makes me assume he was looking to get to the form elements based on their ID.